# How do I make Paper.js package for Meteor work in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, paperjs

After doing: meteor add marcinn:paperjs.

It generates an error because Path is not defined (the paperjs Path() function in framePreview.js)

What is missing (paper.js is present in packages and package list file)

here is my test:

```
---tsite01.html (stands for test site 01)

<head>
<title>tsite01</title>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library--> 
<script type="text/paperscript" src="papers/framePreview.js" canvas="framePreview"> </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{> hello}}   
  <canvas id="framePreview" resize></canvas>
</body>


<template name="hello">
  <button>Click here</button>
  <p>You've pressed the bouton {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

--- framePreview.js  in papers subdirectory

var path=new Path();
path.strokeColor='black';
var start= new Point(100,100);
path.moveTo(start);
path.lineTo(start+[10,-50]);

-- tsite.js

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: Meteor packages are installed in `~/.meteor/packages`. This package should appear in `~/.meteor/packages/marcinn_paperjs`

Answer (score 0):

To make paper.js work in Meteor, the paper function (which wraps the entire library) needs to be displayed in the window.

Let me know if this package helps you:

https://github.com/maddymaxey/Paperjs

To use it, make sure that everything is called with paper. E.g: new paper.Point instead of new Point.

Comment: Your answer is not complete. You should add more information to make it self-contain